# email is going empty when attaching an image with it

Tags: javascript, node.js, sendgrid

```
let message = {
  to: toEmail,
  from: liveCampaign.emailFromAddress,
  subject: liveCampaign.emailSubjectTemplate,
  text: "hi",
  html: '<img src="content_id:myimagecid" alt = "graphics">',
  files: [
    {
      filename: "Christmas2.png",
      content: ("image" | Buffer),
      content_id: "myimagecid",
      contentType: "image/png"
    }
  ]
};
```

i have modified my code but still not able to send the mail .i am getting response error from sendgrid, please somebody help me can somebody provide a syntax of email with attachment in sendgrid

Comment: Attachments should be an array.  Path isn't a valid property, cid should be content_id, and you have no content field.

Comment: let image = base64Img.base64(
    '"file:///C:/work/project/iv-ace/ace/images/Campaign-images/Christmas2.png"',
    function(err, data) {}
  );

  let message = {
    to: toEmail,
    from: liveCampaign.emailFromAddress,
    subject: liveCampaign.emailSubjectTemplate,
    text: "hi",
    html: '<img src="cid:myimagecid" alt = "graphics">',
    files: [
      {
        filename: "Christmas2.png",
        content: ("image" | Buffer),
        cid: "myimagecid",
        contentType: "image/png"
      }
    ]
  };

Comment: here is what i have modified my code as you said but i am getting the error as message: 'Response error',